# SQL add ALL to select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a select statement which displays a list of companies.

```
SELECT distinct [Company]
  FROM [Records]
```

How can I add the entry "ALL" as the first item on the returned list?

Comment: See `UNION`. You will technically have to ORDER BY the entire result-set for guaranteed results, however. Ref http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/10/30/sql-server-union-all-and-order-by-how-to-order-table-separately-while-using-union-all/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union all` and `order by`:

```
select company
from ((select distinct company, 1 as ordering from records)
      union all
      (select 'ALL', 0)
     ) t
order by ordering;
```

In practice, the following would seem to work:

```
select 'ALL' as company
union all
select distinct company from records;
```

However, SQL Server does not guarantee that these are executed in order.  In practice, I have never found a case where this statement would not put `ALL` first, but it is not guaranteed as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` and add order:

```
SELECT [Company] FROM
    (SELECT 'All' as [Company], 0 as RecordOrder
    UNION ALL
    SELECT distinct [Company], 1 as RecordOrder
    FROM [Records]) X
ORDER BY RecordOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

try with union all

```
    SELECT 'ALL'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT distinct [Company]
      FROM [Records]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct [Company]
FROM [Records]
```